# How do I make my discord bot (Discord.js v14.9.0) shutdown, while it's using PM2 Asked today?

Tags: javascript, p-lang

I am trying to make a kill switch for my [**Discord Bot**](https://pmkisanbeneficiarylistwb.in/pm-kisan-status-check/) that uses PM2 to keep it running. After I use the command, PM2 just restarts the bot. How do I kill the process until I restart it manually?

try to best experimentand expecting best suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `--no-autorestart` flag to your pm2 command when you run your script.